# Continuous speech recognition with microphone using speech-recognition library

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I don't understand how to convert continuous speech in text using Google Cloud API in Windows desktop.

I tried speech-recognition sample with Google, Google Cloud and Sphinx engines. With Google I can convert only short speech (up to 10 seconds) to the text. Sphinx works much better but the quality of recognition is very bad comparing to Google.

It is a standard code I found here:
https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/microphone_recognition.py

The results of the actual recognition are fine but it doesn't resolve the problem of the continuous speech recognition. 
I found samples of asynchronous speech recognition via Google Clour service but they all based on the audio file rather than a microphone

Comment: I think Houndify might support something like this but I'm not sure. Otherwise, I think Picovoice has a continuous offline asr you may want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous speech recognition is a specific and difficult task, and requires a recognizer that is specifically built for this task.

None of the web APIs used by the sample code you've linked (Google Cloud APIs and otherwise) support continuous speech recognition. They cannot be used for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, is there a way to implement an asynchronous speech recognition where a process 1 is getting a microphone input whilst a process 2 sending the recognition requests through the API? IN this case you just don't need to wait each time till the recognition is ended.